# Hosted Wasm Blazor App with Let's encrypt. Endpoints not available

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, lets-encrypt, synology, kestrel

I have a hosted Blazor WASM app (.net 7). I want to host it in docker using kestrel , on my synology using a let's encrypt certificate.

Locally on my machine the https seems to work. But when I put my custom xxxx.duckdns.org domain in my host file on my dev machine. And try to run kestrel the asp.net endpoints are not working. The static file hosting and swagger work, with the correct certificate. But the index.html does not load in my browser.

My appsettings. contain

```
  "Kestrel": {
    "Certificates": {
      "Default": {
        "Path": "Cert/fullchain.pem",
        "KeyPath": "Cert/privkey.pem"
      }
    },
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://xxxx.duckdns.org:5151"
      },
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://xxxx.duckdns.org:5152"
      }
    }
```

The log files. Do not add a lot of info.

'Fallback {*path:nonfile}' with route pattern '{*path:nonfile}' is not valid for the request path '/index.html'|

It's like the index.html is not there.

What am I missing ?

Thanks for any clue whatsoever .

I have replaced the the pem file in config, With a 509Certificate that is loaded when Kestrel is configured.  But no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

I created a blank solution project, with Ssl enabled.

There I saw that the client and server launchsettings were in sync.

In my project the launchsettings of my client were not refering to ports of the server.

When I updated that, everything worked.